# Reference a method within a method in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Ok, so I am going to see if this makes sense. In the second method below `(int numAdd)` I want to be used for the `private` method `(int searchingNum)`. I don't really understand how `private` methods work, but whatever number the user enters for the `(int numAdd)` I want to be duplicated for the parameters in the first method. How is this possible?

```
//See if user input returns -1 to test whether or not number exists in the array
private int indexOf(int searchingNum)
{

}

//Add number in the array
public boolean addNumber(int numAdd)
{

    if (list.contains(numAdd))

    {
        return false;

    }
    else 
    {
        list.add(numAdd);   
        count++;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't understand what "to be duplicated" means?

Comment: @TuTran I think he wants to call `indexOf` from `addNumber` and send `numAdd` as an input parameter to `indexOf` method.

Answer (score 1):

that's it? `indexOf(numAdd);`

```
public boolean addNumber(int numAdd)
{
   // somewhere, in the middle of nowhere
   indexOf(numAdd);
  // more of code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call method of same class directly. No need to do anything. Like this :

```
public boolean addNumber(int numAdd)
{
    int abc = indexOf(numAdd);
    //Whatever you want to do...
}
```